# How to clear animations and delete rendered animation frames

Tags: rendering, animation, cache

A real noob question, but even with some googling and searching here, I could not find an answer. Working on my first animation project. I did a basic turntable animation of my character's base mesh with HDR lighting. I wanted to remove the animation/actions from the camera (follow a bezier path and turn to point toward the character). I think I successfully removed all animation-related data. Eventually used bpy-api to clear all actions, just to be sure. The dope sheet and action editor etc., are all empty.

Now I would continue working on the character and manually render images. Still, when I press F12 to render an image, Blender shows me a rendered frame from my previous animation instead of rendering a new image from the current camera position. And indeed, if I move the play head on the Playback timeline and press F12 again, I get another previously rendered image at that frame number.

What is the correct way to delete/clear the Playback(?) so I can continue rendering images manually? I'm on version 3.1.2.

Comment: Hello, maybe you've imported your previous image sequence or video in the Video Sequencer, so if you render that will be the ones that will be rendered. To avoid that, either remove them from the Video Sequencer, or go into the Output panel > Post Processing and disable the Sequencer option. Generally it's better to import your image sequence in a brand new file that you'll only use for video editing

Comment: pls provide your blend file because this can have several reasons. You didn't show us any of your settings so we can just guess. thx.